# Does convergence in probability imply $\sqrt{n}$-consistency?

Tags: probability, convergence, asymptotics

Consider a linear model $y=X\beta+\varepsilon$, and take $\tilde\beta$ as an estimator of the population parameter $\beta$.

If $\left\|\tilde\beta-\beta\right\|_2\rightarrow0$ in probability, does this imply that $\tilde\beta$ is a $\sqrt{n}$-consistent estimator of $\beta$?

I am not used to work in asymptotic theory so I am not sure If what I did is correct, but this is what I have so far: I know that $\left\|\tilde\beta-\beta\right\|_2\rightarrow0$ in probability means that $P(\left\|\tilde\beta-\beta\right\|_2\geq\epsilon)=0$. So from here,

\begin{eqnarray}
 P(\left\|\tilde\beta-\beta\right\|_2\geq\epsilon)=0&\Rightarrow&P((\tilde\beta_1-\beta_1)^2+\ldots+(\tilde\beta_p-\beta_p)^2\geq\epsilon^2)=0\nonumber\\
 &\Rightarrow&P(p(\tilde\beta_1-\beta_1)^2\geq\epsilon^2)=0\nonumber\\
 &\Rightarrow&P(\sqrt{p}|\tilde\beta_1-\beta_1|\geq\epsilon)=0\nonumber
 \end{eqnarray}

Now the definition for being $\sqrt{n}$-consistent is that 
$$P(\sqrt{n}|\tilde\beta-\beta|>K)<\epsilon$$

#### EDTI: Correction based on comments.

So I think that what I got proves consistency, and even a sort of $\sqrt{p}$-consistency. But is there a way to prove the $\sqrt{n}$-consistency?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The second $\Rightarrow$ was not correct, it was a $p$ not an $n$ what should appear there.

Comment: I am afraid this does not make sense: $p$ is the fixed dimension of $\beta$ while $n$ is the sample size increasing to infinity.

Comment: If $\tilde\beta$ converges in probability to $\beta$, then it also converges in distribution. And convergence in distribution implies $\tilde\beta$ is tight or bounded in probability (hints [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2850112/321264)). But not sure if that implies $\sqrt n$ consistency.

Comment: Do you want to examine whether $P(\sqrt{n}|\hat \beta - \beta|> \epsilon) \to 0$, i.e. that the estimator converges to the true value "faster" than $\sqrt{n}$, and so, for example, we would need a higher scaling factor than $\sqrt{n}$ in order to obtain a non-degenerate asymptotic distribution?